# Siegel-Klingen Theorem (Reference request)

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

While studying Dirichlet L-functions and Dedekind zeta functions I stumbled across mentions of the so called Siegel-Klingen theorem on the internet.
However, I have doubts whether the thesis of the Siegel-Klingen theorem is that

1) For all number fields K $\zeta_K(-k)\in\mathbb{Q},k\geq0$;

or if it is

2) For all completely real K $\zeta_K(2k),k\geq1$, is a rational multiple of $|\mathrm{disc}(K)|^{\frac{1}{2}}\pi^{2k N},\, N=[K:\mathbb{Q}]$;

the second statement follows from the first (restricted to when K is completely real) considering the functional equation for $\zeta_K$, and I know how to prove the first statement when K is abelian over $\mathbb{Q}$, by using the analogous fact for Dirichlet L-functions L(s,$\chi$) and the factorization of $\zeta_K$ as product of some of them.

I have done a quick search on google, but I could not find a satisfactory reference in english, so I'd appreciate if someone pointed me out one,if it exists.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a placeholder: in my old book "Holomorphic Hilbert Modular Forms" there is a proof, yes, in English :), of this result. That book does exist in some libraries, and inter-library loan may succeed if you don't have it in yours. I don't know of any other sources (whether in English or German or whatever), but I've not been looking for them or paying attention, either, so that doesn't mean too much about recent sources.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Also, could you tell me which of the two statements I wrote constitutes Siegel-Klingen theorem, and if the first is even true in full generality?

Comment: The non-trivial result only refers to totally real (not "completely real") number fields. E.g., there is "trivial vanishing" at all negative integers for complex quadratic fields, but no "known" positive integer values. The second statement is equivalent to the non-trivial part of the first. There is also a more general analogous result for totally even finite-order characters on totally real fields. I learned this in a course of G. Shimura c. 1975.

Comment: Yes you're right, the correct term is totally real. Also, I somehow missed that $\zeta_K(-k)=0$ for K not totally real and $k\geq1$ until you noted that the first statement is trivial in this case.